# How do the symbols r, o, and i related to the polar coordinates (Rho, Phi, and Theta)

Tags: polar-coordinates

I've been seeing formulas that use the Rho Phi Theta tokens.

Some of these formulas use the symbol forms of them as well

However, a lot of formulas online, and pretty much every programmatic formula of Polar coordinates always use `r, o, i` as the terms for rho phi and theta, but I'm not sure what symbol relates to which coordinate..

I know this isn't technically mathematics, but I'm not sure where else to ask

Right now I understand that these terms relate to each other:

```
Rho   - r, p, ρ
Theta - θ, Θ
Phi   - φ, Φ
```

I just need to understand where o and i fit into the terms for the symbol

[image]

Comment: Could you give a specific example of a program that uses these variables? My guess would be that o is theta and i is phi. You should also be careful that mathematicians and physicists/engineers have different conventions for which angle is theta, which is phi.

Comment: https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/mandelbulb/mandelbulb.htm @AmejiB. Inogo Quilez (A major influence on the creation and optimization of the mandelbulb) uses the symbols R O and I as reference to polar coordinates in pretty much every one of his code snippets

Comment: There are a multitude of conventions for the variable names in spherical coordinates. Probably the most common convention is the physics convention, which is used on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). I personally prefer the mathematics convention, which is used on [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html). But, there are more esoteric conventions to be aware of as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the cartesian transformation that he uses to tell what the angles are.

```
// convert back to cartesian coordinates
    w.x = wr * sin(wo)*sin(wi);
    w.y = wr * cos(wo);
    w.z = wr * sin(wo)*cos(wi);
```

On the other hand, the typical representation (matching your picture) is

$$x = r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi) \\ y = r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi) \\ z = r\cos(\theta)$$

So he is using o for $\theta$ and i for $\varphi$, but his cartesian coordinates are flipped in the sense that w.x is really $y$, w.y is really $z$, and w.z is really $x$.

Comment: Thankyou, that solves a bunch of problems, and that explains why the polar coordinate formulas arent consistent with others. Some programs use XYZ differently, and he has his own custom raymarching engines, so the directions are all a bit awkward.